# Узнать владельца процесса по его ID

Tags: c#

Как можно узнать имя пользователя, владельца объекта класса `Process`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гляньте тут: [How to get the user name or owner of a process in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566835/how-to-get-the-user-name-or-owner-of-a-process-in-net)